# How to save dynamically added partial view data to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have added a feature to add more users information by providing "add another user" link.
This link load a partial view on the page.And when I click save at the end after adding 3 0r 4 user partial view, How can i save this data into database ,

```
$("#addAnotherUserLink").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
               url: this.href,
               cache: false,
               success: function (html) { 
                   $(".userDiv").append(" <div class='userPartialDiv'><a href='#' class='deleteRow'>Delete</a>" + html + "</div>"); 
               }
           });
   return false;
});
```

My view derived from a viewmodel  -- `@model MyApp.DataModels.DemoViewModel`

And controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddUserForm(DemoViewModel demoViewModel)
 {

 }
```

But user partial view is loaded dynamically. How to access that partial view model data into controller.

Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far in your model or controller? What you posted above doesn't have anything to do with MVC

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to answer this question.

Comment: So you post an empty controller method? I suggest you do some research about MVC before posting here asking us to write code for you

Comment: All I am asking here is how to get that dynamically loaded partial view model data into controller. I can see that Demoviewmodel data in controller. But don't know how to access that repeated partial view data. I can write the code from there. I have google'd it and did not find the right solution.

Comment: @mituw16 do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put Users (or DemoViewModel from your controller) view models into List (it can be only one viewmodel, another you will add by javascript) and print it in theview. It will generate inputs with indexes in the name and ID ... something like UsersModels_*1*_Property. When you are adding new row to your form, you have to to ensure that HTML inputs has right index on name and ID. In "create" action you will receave list of User view model.

Here is very good article about your problem http://www.techiesweb.net/asp-net-mvc3-dynamically-added-form-fields-model-binding/

Comment: Link to the article is broken